# Issue with Keras and graph disconnected when using Tensorflow tensors

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to create a `Keras` model that uses some `Tensorflow` functions in it.

The model is based on the `Keras MNIST CNN` example and it consists of a simple stack of convolutional layers followed by the estimation of a `Gaussian`. To evaluate the `Gaussian` function, I estimate its mean and standard deviation using `Dense(2)`. The two parameters are then combined using `tf.range` and `tf.exp` to form a `Gaussian` function. This `Gaussian` tensor is then multiplied by the network to produce the final output.

If I run the model without the `Gaussian` multiplication, everything works fine. When I introduce the `Gaussian` bit, I get the error:

```
RuntimeError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor
  Tensor("Exp_2:0", shape=(?, 9216), dtype=float32) at layer "tf". The
  following previous layers were accessed without issue: ['input_2',
  'conv2d_3', 'conv2d_4', 'max_pooling2d_2', 'dropout_3', 'flatten_2']
```

Here is a fully reproducible script:

```
'''Trains a simple convnet on the MNIST dataset.

Gets to 99.25% test accuracy after 12 epochs
(there is still a lot of margin for parameter tuning).
16 seconds per epoch on a GRID K520 GPU.
'''

from __future__ import print_function
import keras
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Model, Input
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten, Multiply
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras import backend as K

batch_size = 128
num_classes = 10
epochs = 12

# input image dimensions
img_rows, img_cols = 28, 28

# the data, split between train and test sets
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], 1, img_rows, img_cols)
    x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], 1, img_rows, img_cols)
    input_shape = (1, img_rows, img_cols)
else:
    x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 1)
    x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 1)
    input_shape = (img_rows, img_cols, 1)

x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
x_test = x_test.astype('float32')
x_train /= 255
x_test /= 255
print('x_train shape:', x_train.shape)
print(x_train.shape[0], 'train samples')
print(x_test.shape[0], 'test samples')

# convert class vectors to binary class matrices
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)

inputs = Input(shape=input_shape)
net = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                 activation='relu')(inputs)
net = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu')(net)
net = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(net)
net = Dropout(0.25)(net)
net = Flatten()(net)

gauss_par = Dense(2, activation='relu')(net)
# Define a vector from 1 to n_frames
x1d = K.tf.range(0, 9216, dtype='float32')
# Transform the vector into a tensor of shape [batch_size, n_frames]
x = K.tf.tile(K.tf.reshape(x1d, [1, -1]), [K.tf.shape(inputs)[0], 1])
# Gaussian function
gaussian = K.tf.exp(-K.tf.pow(x - gauss_par[:, 0], 2) / 2 / K.tf.pow(gauss_par[:, 1], 2))
# Transform the tensorflow tensor into a keras tensor
gaussian_layer = Input(tensor=gaussian, name='tf')

net = Multiply()([net, gaussian_layer])
net = Dense(128, activation='relu')(net)
net = Dropout(0.5)(net)
outputs = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(net)

model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()
model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=epochs,
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print('Test loss:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
```

Do you have any idea what might be causing this error?